# How can I integrate Perl and Abyss Web Server?

Tags: perl

I don't know Perl. I don't even love it, but i'm obliged to use a script that is coded in Perl.

I have Abyss websever on my PC (I use it both for .net and PHP), I want to know if I can simply download the needed files and link them to the current server; if no can some one link me to a simple Perl server that works.

Thanks

Comment: I fix problems where I find them to make the world a better place. It's not OCPD. I'm a real-life editor and maintainer of Perl documentation. Other parts of Stackoverflow would be so lucky to have someone care about quality.

Comment: @brian d foy - Yeah, listen, maybe I little overreacted there. When I'm stuck at 4 A.M. with some stupid task, little things tend to annoy me greatly. And your edit just popped up at a bad time. Apologies for the comment (deleting it now).

Comment: "I don't know Perl. I don't even love it". Besides being rather weird as a statement of consequence (ignorance->dislike), the introduction is pretty bad when expecting help from people that know and love Perl.

Comment: lol...yeah that could be worded less harsh.. Im not a Perl lover either and I took it offensive

Comment: @nxadm sorry because I really HATE IT and it's code makes me nervous :D but I need the script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [Aprelium's instructions for integrating ActiveState and Abyss](http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/perl.html).

Comment: everday this small server is surprising me with new features and super support, they are really good, thanks for being attentive for the tutorial

Answer (score 5):

You could have just downloaded **free** [Apache Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) to handle the job

Comment: Actually Abyss Web Server X1 is also free for personal use.